# drag and drop feature created using jquery.ui/draggable, currently facing one issue that how to create scroll div in dropable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In the below demo there are some inputs that we can drag and drop in the drop-zone. What I need is there any possibility that if user dragging any element then that drop-zone should be scroll-able. We have one property named `"scroll:true"` but it is not working. For demo please check below link

https://codepen.io/piyushSinghalDemo/pen/ddNBVv?editors=1000

```
$draggableOperators.draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  opacity: 0.7,
  scroll: true,
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: 'body',
  zIndex: 1000,
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var elOffset = ui.offset;
    var containerOffset = $flowchart.offset();
    if (elOffset.left > containerOffset.left && elOffset.top > containerOffset.top && elOffset.left < containerOffset.left + $flowchart.width() && elOffset.top < containerOffset.top + $flowchart.height()) {
      var flowchartOffset = $flowchart.offset();
      var relativeLeft = elOffset.left - flowchartOffset.left;
      var relativeTop = elOffset.top - flowchartOffset.top;
      var positionRatio = $flowchart.flowchart('getPositionRatio');
      relativeLeft /= positionRatio;
      relativeTop /= positionRatio;
      var data = getOperatorData($this);
      data.left = relativeLeft;
      data.top = relativeTop;
      $flowchart.flowchart('addOperator', data);
    }
  }
});
```

drag and drop feature created using jquery.ui/draggable library, however currently facing one issue that how to create scroll div in droppable area codepan for demo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is vague and not very clear. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what is exactly not working. This is not a complete example.

Comment: yes for complete demo i have added codepen link "https://codepen.io/piyushSinghalDemo/pen/ddNBVv?editors=1000"

Comment: Suspect this is related to CSS for the drop zone. It has no content or overflow.